# Problem with PHP & SQL Query

Tags: php, sql, insert

I have a problem in php code inserting values into database (I use PHPMyAdmin).

My DATABASE has 3 tables:

1. `Member` with this fields: MemberID, MemberName
2. `Room` with this fields: RoomID, RoomName
3. `Join` with this fields: MemberID, RoomID

The idea is to join the member in the room.

My query was

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO join (RoomID, MemberID) VALUES ('121', '131')");
```

but unfortunately it does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) is a reserved keyword. You might be able to escape it using backticks

```
INSERT INTO `join` (RoomID, MemberID) VALUES ('121', '131')
```

but I would suggest renaming the table if possible.

Answer (score 2):

`JOIN` is a reserved word in most flavours of SQL.
Try putting the database name before the table name

```
insert into dbname.join (RoomID,MemberID) ....
```

Or better yet, rename the table `join` to something else.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the table name in backticks:

```
insert into `join` (RoomID,MemberID) values ('121', '131')
```

Because "join" is an SQL keyword, the parser will get confused if you try to also use it as a name without explicitly making it a name via the ticks.

In the future, you probably don't want to name tables as things that are already SQL keywords - instead, name them something more descriptive, like "RoomsAndMembers" or some such.